# How to handle multiple canvases in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, react-ref

I want to display 2 canvases on a single page which I am storing in an array in the state of the class. Basic code-

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.myRef1 = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        isDrawing: false,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        boards: [<canvas className="wb-canvas" ref={this.myRef} width={800} height={400} id={1} />, <canvas className="wb-canvas" ref={this.myRef1} width={800} height={400} id={2} />],
    };
}
```

I have a switch button, which on clicking should switch the two boards. `switch()` function-

```
switch() {
    let a = this.state.boards[0];
    let b = this.state.boards[1];
    this.setState({
        boards: [b, a],
    });
    console.log(this.state.boards);
}
```

Suppose I draw a tree on top canvas and a flower on bottom. On clicking switch, the two canvas elements switch successfully(visible in developer tools) but the tree still appears on the top one and flower on the bottom one, i.e. it looks as if canvases didn't switch on the webpage.

I tried using `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` for the canvases but that didn't seem to work too.

I am confused why this is happening? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try adding unique "key" attribute to both canvases according to https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html . I guess you are rendering `this.state.boards` in `render()` which is a list of components, React might not detect when you swap them unless you explicitly set "key".

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRadionov. That worked!